# Jsoup - handling links with Javascript in their href attribute

Tags: java, javascript, jsoup

i am trying to parse data from a webpage which is structured in a way like, 20 records per sheet 
i am able to get the first 20 records and then i have to move to the second sheet, the second sheet link is as shown below

```
<a href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$amfiHomeContent$gvArnSearch','Page$2')">2</a>
```

the href element has some javascript that loads the next 20 records. when it does, the url remains same.

the Javascript which is called

```
var theForm = document.forms['aspnetForm'];
if (!theForm) {
    theForm = document.aspnetForm;
}
function __doPostBack(eventTarget, eventArgument) {
    if (!theForm.onsubmit || (theForm.onsubmit() != false)) {
        theForm.__EVENTTARGET.value = eventTarget;
        theForm.__EVENTARGUMENT.value = eventArgument;
        theForm.submit();
    }
}
```

how can i handle this part in jsoup? is it even possible?
thanks in advance.

Comment: Jsoup cannot do JavaScript. When you load the next page in a browser, does it actually go to another page (even though the URL stays the same), or does it just load the next records into the same page ? Have a look at the "network" tab in your browser's development console, and see what gets loaded. Possibly, it is JSON or similar, which you could download and parse in some way.

Comment: Try seeing this question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20171567/login-a-website-with-jsoup-post-method