# Jsoup to connect to a "Javascript" link

Tags: java, authentication, jsoup

Consider the following link:

```
<a id="login" class="js-check" rel="nofollow" data-nop="" ref="javascript:void(0)">Login</a>
```

Through Jsoup, I can retrieve this element as follows:

```
Element bodyElement = doc.body();
Element A_Login = bodyElement.getElementById("login");
```

Now, I would like to follow this link with Jsoup and I'm no sure how I can do this?

FWIW, in the browser, clicking this link yields a registration/login form:

```
<form id="login_form" method="post" action="https://www.link.com/forum/login/">
  <table class="formTable">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td><label class="required" for="login_login">Login</label></td>
        <td><input id="login_login" type="text" required="required" name="login[login]"> </td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td><label class="required" for="login_password">Password</label></td>
        <td><input id="login_password" type="password" required="required" name="login[password]"></td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td><button type="submit">Login</button></td>
     </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
</form
```

Of course, the above login form is asynchronously loaded, and not part to the "base" HTML contents..

How can I use Jsoup to login in such situations?

Comment: I'm pretty sure Jsoup cannot act on JavaScript like you are wanting. Is your end goal to login to that form? Unless your situation requires you to scrape data and follow those links beforehand, if you know the URL in the form action, why not have Jsoup work with that URL and pass in login info similar to this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20317262/985709

Answer (score 0):

Jsoup does not interpret Javascript. So you either need to analyze the script yourself and create appropriate urls that the simple JSoup http client can load, or you can use a full browser to get the link. Selenium http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.jsp in combination with phantomjs http://phantomjs.org/ are are a good solution for that.

Comment: I see. that's unfortunate. What do you mean by "analyze the script yourself and create appropriate urls that the simple JSoup http client can load"? How can I determine what is this URL? Or even if it exists.. ? Tried through Firebug, but didnt have much luck..

Comment: I mean you need to reverse engineer that code. It might be way too much work, depending on the javascript you need to study. About the url you were on the right track with firebug. The network tab should list all requests and its parameters, including the ones generated by the JavaScript in question. By the way - don't forget to upvote and accept answers if you feel they helped/solved the problem.