# What is the best way to Log In and exchange information with a https website from your Android App?

Tags: android, authentication, android-volley, httpclient

Lately I have been trying to create an App to Log In to a HTTPS website and save some information from that website. I tried to use the library `Volley` but for some reasons cookies were not saved and so I couldn't Log In. 
I realized also that `DefaultHttpClient` is deprecated. 
So what are the best libraries/ways that support HTTPS to Log In to a website from an app?

Comment: Use Retrofit library.. https://square.github.io/retrofit/

Answer (score 0):

I would use Jsoup, with it you can easily access the document and extract information too.

A call would look like

```
//With this you login and a session is created
    Connection.Response res = Jsoup.connect("http://techmvs.technion.ac.il:80/cics/wmn/wmngrad?aapmlkwi&ORD=1&s=1")
        .data("username", "myUsername", "password", "myPassword")
        .method(Method.POST)
        .execute();

//This will get you cookies
Map<String, String> loginCookies = res.cookies();

//Here you parse the page that you want. Put the url that you see when you have logged in
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("urlYouNeedToBeLoggedInToAccess")
      .cookies(loginCookies)
      .get();
```

As you can see you can access the cookies and use them to open the restricted url. Example is taken from  [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20171567/login-a-website-with-jsoup-post-method).

Answer (score 0):

Use retrofit-2 and Ion or Loop j whatever easy for you but keep in your mind that these library is not given by Google but volley is Google library so it would not be Payable but these third party library may be pain in future.

In other way, These library provides lots of good and easy work with better performance like retry,caching etc.
 so right now you may use but not for future.